# Open tiff image stack in python with gdal

Tags: python, image, tiff, gdal

I'm trying to open a tiff stack using gdal in python.  It is a single file, within which are mutliple tiff files.  When I open it in ImageJ, I can scroll through the stack.  But doing "gdal.Open(file).ReadAsArray() only loads the first tiff file.  Is there a way I can load the whole stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `GetSubDatasets` and (in case all TIFF pages have the same dimensions) create a single numpy array:

```
import numpy, gdal, gdalconst
dataset = gdal.Open("multipage.tiff", gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
data = numpy.array([gdal.Open(name, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly).ReadAsArray()
                    for name, descr in dataset.GetSubDatasets()])
```